# Absolute Galois groups and representations

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-representations

I've thinking about the possibility how is the image of a two dimensional complex representations of absolute galois group of $\mathbb Q$, $G_\mathbb Q$.

I thought I had a proof about what the image is like but it was wrong.

I writing my attempts and conjectures about this.

Let

$$\rho:G_\mathbb Q\to\text{GL}_2(\mathbb C) $$

be a continuous unitary irreducible representation of $G_\mathbb Q$.

It is well known that $\rho$ factors through a finite Galois extension $K/\mathbb Q$ i.e. we have

$$\rho:\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)\to\text{GL}_2(\mathbb C).$$

I have two question about the image of this representations:

1. There exist an a representations equivalent to $\rho$ such that the matrix coefficients  always are algebraic numbers i.e. if the image consists of matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix}
   a & b \\
   c & d 
   \end{pmatrix}$ then, a,b,c,d are algebraic numbers?
2. I've thinking in the possibility that the response of the question is affirmative, but I have not found the right way. And even, I think that if the conjecture is wrong then you can look at certain special elements such that the matrix coefficients are algebraic, for example on conjugacy class of the Frobenius elements.

I appreciate you any suggestion, or an counterexample.

Thanks you all

Comment: You can always define a representation by $A\rho(g)A^{-1}$ for any invertible complex matrix $A$, so the coefficients can be basically anything (though of course they have to satisfy some relations).

Comment: Sorry i edited the question

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes. This has absolutely nothing to do with Galois groups or anything else.  Every representation of a finite group is defined over algebraic numbers.

Comment: please could you give me an idea of the proof?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez you have any reference about this question please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of irreducible representations of a finite group G over an algebraically closed field K of characteristic zero is equal to the number of conjugacy classes — this follows at once from Wedderburn's theorem applied to the group algebra KG. In particular, the numbers of irreducible representations of G over $\mathbb C$ and over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ are the same.

This implies immediately that every complex representation is defined over the algebraic numbers. Since it is moreover finite dimensional and the group has finitely many elements, it is defined over a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ — consider the field generated by all entries of all matrices representing all elements of the group.

Comment: A field over which all representation are defined is called a splitting field. If you look for that term you will find lots of information. In particular , the book by Curtis and Reiner is a good reference.

Comment: If one works harder you can show that one need only add to Q an primitive nth root of unity, with n the order of G. And if you work much harder you can get this down to an primitive eth root of unity, with e the exponent of G. These are two theorems of Brauer which should be an all good books.

Comment: And if you work still harder you can show that you can realize all representations over the algebraic integers of some number field. This theorem should be in Curtis and Reiner.

Comment: thanks appreciate you help